# Save data of ArrayList in Android

Tags: java, android

I request data from a link on the internet using Volley.
In that link there are four objects and I added them to the array.
If I now want to add another object or remove that object from the array after restarting the application. The data of the array remains as I have manipulated them. How to get back after data extraction has not been lost?

Comment: and the question is?

Answer (score 0):

Seems looks like you need.
CoreUser is a model, you also use it like array.

```
public static void updateCoreUserInfo(Context context, CoreUser coreUser) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(coreUser);
    CacheHelper.write(context, CoreUser.OBJECT_NAME, json);
}

public static CoreUser getCoreUserInfo(Context context) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = CacheHelper.read(context, CoreUser.OBJECT_NAME, "");
    return gson.fromJson(json, CoreUser.class);
}

 compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
public class CacheHelper {
    private static final String PREFS_NAME = "com.example.appname";

    private static SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(Context context) {
        return context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public static void write(Context context, String name, String value) {
        if (CacheHelper.getSharedPreferences(context).edit()
                .putString(name, value)
                .commit()) {
        }
    }

    public static void write(Context context, String name, float value) {
        if (CacheHelper.getSharedPreferences(context).edit()
                .putString(name, String.valueOf(value))
                .commit()) {
        }
    }

    public static void write(Context context, String name, long value) {
        if (CacheHelper.getSharedPreferences(context).edit()
                .putLong(name, value)
                .commit()) {
        }
    }


    public static void write(Context context, String name, int value) {
        if (CacheHelper.getSharedPreferences(context).edit()
                .putInt(name, value)
                .commit()) {
        }
    }

    public static void writeBool(Context context, String name, boolean value) {
        if (CacheHelper.getSharedPreferences(context).edit()
                .putBoolean(name, value)
                .commit()) {
        }
    }

    public static String read(Context context, String name, String defaultValue) {
        return CacheHelper.getSharedPreferences(context)
                .getString(name, defaultValue);
    }

    public static int read(Context context, String name, int defaultValue) {
        return CacheHelper.getSharedPreferences(context)
                .getInt(name, defaultValue);
    }

    public static long read(Context context, String name, long defaultValue) {
        return CacheHelper.getSharedPreferences(context)
                .getLong(name, defaultValue);
    }

    public static double read(Context context, String name, double defaultValue) {
        return Double.parseDouble(CacheHelper.getSharedPreferences(context)
                .getString(name, String.valueOf(defaultValue)));
    }

    public static float read(Context context, String name, float defaultValue) {
        return Float.parseFloat(CacheHelper.getSharedPreferences(context)
                .getString(name, String.valueOf(defaultValue)));
    }

    public static boolean read(Context context, String name, boolean defaultValue) {
        return CacheHelper.getSharedPreferences(context)
                .getBoolean(name, defaultValue);
    }

    private static void clearCacheUtil(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        settings.edit().clear().commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**SharedPreferances** allow you to save primitive types like Boolean, Float, Int, Long, String etc.For this you need to add Google [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) lib.

**For Inserting Data to SharedPreferances**

```
List<CustomObj> customList = "**get your list**"
String listStr = new Gson().toJson(customList);

SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(**"prefes_key"**, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString(**"your_prefes_key"**, listStr);
editor.apply();
```

**For getting Data From SharedPreferances**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(**"prefes_key"**, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String clistStr = prefs.getString(**"prefes_key"**, ""); 

List<CustomObj> requiredList =  
new Gson().fromJson(clistStr, new TypeToken<List<CustomObj>>() {
            }.getType());
```